# Newbie - If image field empty use current profile picture - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day, I am writing a PHP page to update a user's profile details, such as first name, last name, email address mobile number and a profile picture. **Everything works fine, I can update a profile picture and store the file name and extension in the database and display it wherever I want to.**

**BUT**

Let's say **today** I update my profile picture.
Let's say **tomorrow** I  want to change **only one** detail **(MY NAME)**

When you update only one detail, I think the file input is empty.
**Is there a way to use the value already existing in the database for the profile picture instead of updating an empty field???**

```
<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>
```

***PHP CODE:***

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
    {   
header('location:login.php');
}
else{

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $folder="assets/images/user-pp/";

    /* new file size in KB */
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    /* new file size in KB */

    /* make file name in lower case */
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    /* make file name in lower case */

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $idedit=$_POST['editid'];
    $image=$_POST['image'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
        {
            $image=$final_file;
        }

    $sql="UPDATE users SET firstname=(:firstname), lastname=(:lastname), email=(:email), mobile=(:mobile), Image=(:image) WHERE id=(:idedit)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':idedit', $idedit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $msg="Information Updated Successfully";
}    
?>
```

***HTML FORM***

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="javascript: void(0);">
        <img src="assets/images/user-pp/<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>" class="rounded mr-75" alt="profile image" height="64" width="64"></a>
      <div class="media-body mt-75">
        <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-start">
          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-50 mb-50 mb-sm-0 cursor-pointer" for="account-upload">Upload new photo</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="account-upload" class="form-control" hidden>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>">
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning ml-50">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <p class="text-muted ml-75 mt-50"><small>Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 800kB</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-username">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->firstname);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your first name is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-username">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->lastname);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your last name is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-name">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->email);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your email address is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-e-mail">Mobile</label>
          <input type="tel" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->mobile);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your mobile number is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="editid" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>">


    <?php
              
               if($error){?>
    <h5 class="danger">
      <?php echo htmlentities($error); ?>
    </h5>

    <?php }
               
               else if($msg){?>
    <h5 class="success">
      <?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?>
    </h5>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-end">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-1 mb-1 mb-sm-0">Save
                                                                changes</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Build the query dynamically and only update fields with data (or changes if you wanna get fancy).

Comment: Like I said = Newbie!

Comment: have a simple alternative SQL version for when `empty( $_FILES['image'] )` - bind the variables accordingly

Comment: Sorry to ask, but can you help me with that? I am a complete newbie:))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was basic, but it took some hard thinking, LOL, for someone who has only been dabbling with code for two months;)

Instead of trying to set a default value for the file input field, rather set the php/mysql at the top of the form page to check

1. is the file size bigger than 0?

   - if so, then update all fields including profile picture / avatar / file
2. (else)

   - update only specified other fields

      **HERE IS HOW**

***php at the top of page***

```html
-<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0)
 { 
  header('location:login.php');
 }
else{

if(isset($_POST[submit]))
 {
  if($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
   {
    $file = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $folder="assets/images/user-pp/";
    
    /* make file name in lower case */
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    /* make file name in lower case */
    
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
    
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $idedit=$_POST['editid'];
    $image=$_POST['image'];

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
     {
      $image=$final_file;
     }
    
    $sql="UPDATE users SET firstname=(:firstname), lastname=(:lastname), email=(:email), mobile=(:mobile), Image=(:image) WHERE id=(:idedit)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':idedit', $idedit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $msg="Information Updated Successfully";
   }
  else {
    $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $idedit=$_POST['editid'];
    
    $sql="UPDATE users SET firstname=(:firstname), lastname=(:lastname), email=(:email), mobile=(:mobile) WHERE id=(:idedit)";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query-> bindParam(':idedit', $idedit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $msg="Information Updated Successfully";
   }
  
 }    
?>
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="javascript: void(0);">
        <img src="assets/images/user-pp/<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>" class="rounded mr-75" alt="profile image" height="64" width="64"></a>
      <div class="media-body mt-75">
        <div class="col-12 px-0 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-start">
          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-50 mb-50 mb-sm-0 cursor-pointer" for="account-upload">Upload new photo</label>
          <input type="file" name="image" id="account-upload" class="form-control" hidden>
          <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning ml-50">Reset</button>
        </div>
        <p class="text-muted ml-75 mt-50"><small>Allowed JPG, GIF or PNG. Max size of 800kB</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-username">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->firstname);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your first name is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-username">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->lastname);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your last name is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-name">Email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->email);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your email address is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
          <label for="account-e-mail">Mobile</label>
          <input type="tel" name="mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->mobile);?>" required data-validation-required-message="Your mobile number is required!">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="editid" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>">
    <?php 
      if($error){?>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible mb-2" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="danger" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <p class="mb-0">
          <?php echo htmlentities($error); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php } 
                      
            else if($msg){?>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible mb-2" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                  </button>
        <p class="mb-0">
          <?php echo htmlentities($msg); ?>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php }
              
           ?>

    <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-sm-row flex-column justify-content-end">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-sm-1 mb-1 mb-sm-0">Save
                                                                changes</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code bellow and see if this solves what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['alogin'])==0) {   
    header('location:login.php');
}

function fileUpload() {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
        $folder = "assets/images/user-pp/";

        /* new file size in KB */
        $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
        /* new file size in KB */

        /* make file name in lower case */
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        /* make file name in lower case */

        $final_file = str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

        try {
            //throw exception if can't move the file
            if (!move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder.$final_file)) {
                throw new Exception('Could not move file');
            }
            return $final_file;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('File did not upload: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }  
    }          
    return "";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $firstname  = !empty($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : '';
    $lastname   = !empty($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : '';
    $email      = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $mobile     = !empty($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : '';
    $idedit     = !empty($_POST['idedit']) ? $_POST['idedit'] : '';
    $image      = fileUpload();


    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET ";
        if($firstname != '') { $sql .= "firstname=(:firstname)"; }
        if($lastname != '') { $sql .= ", lastname=(:lastname)"; }
        if($email != '') { $sql .= ", email=(:email)"; }
        if($mobile != '') { $sql .= ", mobile=(:mobile)"; }
        if($image != '') { $sql .= ", Image=(:image)"; }
        if($idedit != '') { $sql .= " WHERE id=(:idedit)"; }

        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        if($firstname != '') { $query-> bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
        if($lastname != '') { $query-> bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
        if($email != '') { $query-> bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
        if($mobile != '') { $query-> bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
        if($image != '') { $query-> bindParam(':image', $image, PDO::PARAM_STR); }
        if($idedit != '') { $query-> bindParam(':idedit', $idedit, PDO::PARAM_STR); }       
        $query->execute();

        $msg="Information Updated Successfully";
    } catch (Exception $e) { 
        /* if something fails inside try block will be catched here */
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: if no new file has been selected, then, the value for image should be fetched from the database for the current logged in user and use the same image that was uploaded previously.

Comment: Did you try it? 
With this code you are going to update only the values that are not empty. If no file is uploaded then you are not going to update the image value in the database.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in I:\xampp\htdocs\account-settings.php on line 29

Comment: I corrected my code (a useless opening parenthesis), try again please.

Comment: ```<input type="file" name="image" class="form-control"><input type="hidden" name="image" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->image);?>">```